# how find indexes of sorted data in the original array?

Tags: matlab, sorting

let us consider following code

```
>> B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
>> [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,[],[],100);
>> [peaks,location]=findpeaks(pxx);
>> [sorted_peaks,i]=sort(peaks,'descend');
>> stem(sorted_peaks)
>> plot(location,peaks)
>> plot(f,pxx)
>>
```

my aim is that also arrange frequencies according to sorted peaks, i have sorted it descending,so my goal  that at first place should be frequencies at which maximum of sorted_peak is occurred and so on,so how can i manage it?thanks in advance

EDITED:
is that correct way?

```
>> freq=f(location);
>> freq(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your edit would indeed be the correct way:

```
>> freq_peaks        = f(location);
>> sorted_freq_peaks = freq_peaks (i);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood,

```
location(i)
```

would give you the sorted order of the matching peaks.

So

```
sorted_locations = locations(i)
plot(sorted_locations, sorted_peaks)
```

would give you the matching plot.